# Pass function from Javascript to VB6 application

Tags: javascript, vb6

Is it posible to pass a function from Javascript to Visual Basic 6 (The function will pass data as a string to visual basic 6)? I have googled but am only coming across Javascript to Visual Basic .NET.

I want to integrate two programs: One program runs on a browser which uses the JavaScript, the other program connects with a fiscal printer (actually it is OpenERP).

Since OpenERP does not incorporate fiscal printer functionality that is why I want to add a print button to the point of sale of the OpenERP. When I click that button the sales data will be sent to the visual basic program.

I have written a program in Visual basic which is working properly (program which only connects with the fiscal printer), the problem am having is to connect to the two. Is there any way to do that or I will have to go to .net?

Comment: Yes, you need to write much about your problem, it is very hard to understand what you are doing or want to do. Explain!

Comment: @Stefan,Kant I have edited the question.I guess its more clear.

Comment: Assuming it's all on the same computer (no website involved) then you can have JavaScript write to local file then the VB6 can read from that file. Is this a valid option for you?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I had tried that to write like a .txt file using javascript and then the Visual basic to read that .txt file.The problem is that the one using the program is not much of a computer expert and then the program is used in a supermarket.So the user may have problem of first of all writing the data and then go to the visual basic to print it but thanks.

Comment: No, I mean have code read and write the file, it will be totally transparent to the end user who should not touch the file at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard will the javascript function automate printing of file(when the data is written in a local file will the javascript make the visual basic program print immediately?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your visual basic program you can use the winsock control and write yourself a web-server which then should be proxied through the web-server the javascript code you run in the browser is served from.

The javascript code then can fire a HTTP request to your vb6 application which then can process the data. You then have some kind of remote procedure call (RPC).

Just some pointers:

- Webserver in Visual Basic 6; e.g. http://forum.codecall.net/topic/42076-how-to-create-a-web-server-in-visual-basic-6/
- JSPON-RPC; e.g. http://json-rpc.org/